# Bootstrap dropdown nav menu item wrap (wordpress)

Tags: css

Having trouble getting the submenu items under "LEARN" to wrap (Articles / Videos). 
influentagency.com/clients/cgc_build_062117

I've pasted some of my SASS code, tried different things, but nothing seems to work. Added the wp_bootstrap_navwalker function, tried adding classes, does not wrap no matter what I try.

Any ideas what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

```css
.dropdown-menu > .active > a, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #777; 
   
}

.dropdown-menu {
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}



.navbar{
    border-radius: 0;
    webkit-border-radius: 0;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    &.navbar-default {
        border: none;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 0 15px;
        #navbar-menu{
            float: right;
            &.navbar-collapse{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                .navbar-nav{
                    float: none;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    li{
                        display: inline-block;
                        float: none;
                        margin: 23px 0 0 0px;
                        a {
                            color: #333;
                            font-size: 14px;
                            display: block;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            @include OpenSansSemiBold;
                            padding: 4px 8px;
                            &:hover{
                                color: #9dcb94;
                            }
                        }
                        &.item-right{
                            margin-left: 25px;
                            a{
                                background: $green;
                                color: #fff;
                                border-radius: 2px;
                                padding: 10px 14px;
                                &:hover{
                                    background: $green_hover;
                                }
                            }
                            &.current-menu-item,
                            &.current_page_item,
                            &.current-menu-ancestor,
                            &.current-page-ancestor {
                                a{
                                    color: #fff;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        &.current-menu-item,
                        &.current_page_item,
                        &.current-menu-ancestor,
                        &.current-page-ancestor {
                            a{
                                color: $green;
                            }
                        }
                        .sub-menu{
                            display: none;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your css is making *all* menu items `display-inline`, even ones in the dropdown menus:

```
.navbar.navbar-default #navbar-menu.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    /* other styles here also */
}
```

You need to include the following in your css to override that:

```
.navbar.navbar-default #navbar-menu.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li{
     display:block;
```

}

To do this, you need to add the following to your SASS:

```
.navbar-nav{
    [...]
    li{
        display: inline-block;
        [...]
    }
    .dropdown-menu li { display:block;}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this and still does not wrap. The menu names are short, I'm wondering if there's something else getting in the way.

Comment: No, its definitely the `inline-block`, simply changing that in the Element Inspector in Chrome makes it work. `inline-block` is used to make the elements line up side-by-side. `block`makes it display on its own [See here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/). I can see in the element inspector that it hasn't been changed to `block` in the link you posted, so confirm that the sass had no errors and check in the generated css file to make sure it has `display:block`

Comment: Thank you again.  It was my sass, nested incorrectly, but got it working. Much appreciated!